# SSL over anything?

Tags: python, ssl

I would like to use SSL over something other than sockets. The `ssl` TLS/SSL wrapper is only for socket objects.

For example I have my own IPC class such as:

```
class MyIPC: 
    def recv(self):
        return self.received_data if self.data else None

    def send(self, message): 
        self._send(message)
```

In these scheme I would like to wrap this above class to the `ssl` Python module. Is this something possible.

Notice this `MyIPC` class is p2p communication. In the real world. I would like to use MQTT for the data exchange.

I guess one option is to write a duck-type class to mimic a Socket Object, but I am sure there is a better option.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. MQTT belongs to the application layer and typically **is** used over TCP sockets. And thus I don't see any obstacle to run it over SSL/TLS. What do you mean by "other than sockets"? TLS is specifically designed to work over sockets, nothing else. Or are you looking for custom message encryption?

Comment: Not really. MQTT uses TCP sockets from one node to the broker. However it does not ensure a secured connection from a node to another. This is absolutely normal because MQTT is not a p2p communication protocol.

Comment: Because there is no such thing as connection from a node to another. That concept **doesn't** exist in MQTT. What are you trying to achieve? Are you looking for a custom message encryption?

Comment: I am looking for a way to use standard x509 certificates to secure a communication between two nodes.

Comment: @freakish I am implementing a custom exchange protocol over MQTT for configuring devices. This exchange protocol is very similar to pure sockets I have instances `bob = Tunnel(); alice = Tunnel(); bob.bind(alice), alice.bind(bob); bob.send("Hello Bob");`.

Comment: That said with MQTT v5 there is a new Request/Response Pattern supported which looks more like a Socket.

Comment: I still don't understand why you mix application layer with transport layer. Whatever the protocol is you can either run it over TCP or SSL/TLS. That's completely independent on the protocol. But the transport layer works only between two peers. If you wish to extend encryption further you need some other protocol that on one hand understand where to push messages and on the other does it in secure way. But the real question is: why can't you use MQTT over TLS? For both client-broker and then broker-client connections?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172388/discussion-between-nowox-and-freakish).

Comment: If performance is not an issue then you can use asymmetrical encryption where all nodes share the public key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With recent versions of Python (3.5+) one is no longer bound to use SSL only with sockets but one can use memory buffers as a more abstract layer. How these buffers are the transferred to the peer is up to the application, i.e. it can use sockets directly but also implement protocols such as [this proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-friel-tls-over-http-00) which essentially transports the SSL memory buffers by encoding these into base64 inside JSON and transporting then this JSON within a weakly authenticated HTTPS channel.

To use memory buffers follow [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#memory-bio-support) or have a look at [example code](http://blog.povilasb.com/posts/python-ssl-memorybio-usage/).

Comment: TLS in base64 over JSON through HTTP over SSL over TCP, when one needs just plain SSL over TCP... I'm not sure I want to live in a world where this seems a sensible solution to implement...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: This was added as an example what kind of weird things are possible (and what people try to standardize) and not of what one should really do. I mean, HTTP(S) can easily transport binary data so why pack the stuff in JSON + base64? But at least its not XML  or maybe even a full SOAP call with the TLS payload inside :)